# get vue component in different page with button click on another vue component or html button click

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I want to load a vue component in different page with the html button click.

-HTML button

```
<a class="contentButton ml-n5" id="addCategoryPrice">Add Price<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
```

-Vue Component

```
<add-price></add-price>
```

if this is not possible, then is there any way to get vue component in different page with button click on another vue component.

Comment: you can use vuex  to communicate btw components. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: You can use native click on Vue components. `<add-price @click.native="functionHere"></add-price>` .If this is not the case please provide more info. Also you can pass hrefLink as prop to add-price component. You are free to use one of them :)

Comment: @WebMan you wont be able to communicate to another page like that

Comment: I want to get the vue component with the HTML button click and that component should appear at different page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my R&D there were no solution with redirecting to different page. therefore I have decided to hide the content of existing page with button click in vue component and show the the content which I want with button click.

-Get Vue component in blade

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <add-price>

    </add-price>
</div>
```

-Vue component

**#ListTable** (id of existing content of the page)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="contentButton ml-n5" id="addPrice" @click="addPrice">Add Price<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "AddPrice",
  data() {
    return {
      isShow: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPrice: function (){
      let x = $('#ListTable');
      x.hide();
      this.isShow = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks everyone!